# Change name with while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

First I wrote the iris dataset, then I need to rename the setosa, virginica and versicolors to a,b and c. I then need to double-write these letters with a while loop. For example; I wrote b instead of Setosa, I should call it bb with while loop

```
Burak=iris
sehir= c("zonguldak","bilecik","samsun","sinop","letter")
for ( i in 1:ncol(Burak)) {
  colnames(Burak)[i] = sehir[i]
 
}
head(Burak)




levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "a")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'a'

levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "b")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'setosa'] <- 'b'

levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "c")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'versicolor'] <- 'c'





running_index <- 5


while(is.character(iris[ , running_index])) {              
  
  iris[ , running_index] <- iris[ , running_index] + a
  
  running_index <- running_index +5
  
}
```

Comment: *"I wrote A instead of Setosa"* is wrong, you wrote à`(lower case). Which is it that you want?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one. just trying to figure out how I can replace letters with loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way.

1. Find out which columns are factors with a `sapply` loop:
2. Coerce those factors to character;
3. Find out which columns are of class character;
4. Finally, do the required transformation in a `lapply` loop.

```r
data(iris, package = "datasets")
Burak <- iris
sehir <- c("zonguldak","bilecik","samsun","sinop","letter")
names(Burak) <- sehir

i_fac <- sapply(Burak, is.factor)
Burak[i_fac] <- lapply(Burak[i_fac], as.character)
i_chr <- sapply(Burak, is.character)

Burak[i_chr] <- lapply(Burak[i_chr], \(x) {
  x <- letters[match(x, unique(x))]
  paste0(x, x)
})

head(Burak)
#>   zonguldak bilecik samsun sinop letter
#> 1       5.1     3.5    1.4   0.2     aa
#> 2       4.9     3.0    1.4   0.2     aa
#> 3       4.7     3.2    1.3   0.2     aa
#> 4       4.6     3.1    1.5   0.2     aa
#> 5       5.0     3.6    1.4   0.2     aa
#> 6       5.4     3.9    1.7   0.4     aa

str(Burak)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ zonguldak: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ bilecik  : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ samsun   : num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ sinop    : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ letter   : chr  "aa" "aa" "aa" "aa" ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you need the original factors to still be factors, run

```
Burak[i_fac] <- lapply(Burak[i_fac], as.factor)
```

---

The code above can be rewritten in just one `lapply` loop. The results are identical.

```r
Burak[] <- lapply(Burak, \(x) {
  y <- if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x
  if(is.character(y)) {
    u <- unique(y)
    y <- letters[match(y, u)]
    y <- paste0(y, y)
  }
  if(is.factor(x)) y <- factor(y)
  y
})
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>